# How can I get the generated MANIFEST.MF file from the maven-war-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

As part of my build process, I am generating a separate artifact (compressed file with static web files inside) in the which I would like to contain the same information that is in the manifest file generated by the war plugin. The manifest file is generated correctly into the war file, but I'd like access to it so I can copy it and put it in my compressed file as well.

In the documentation for the maven-war-plugin:manifest goal, it reads:

> The manifest file is created in the warSourceDirectory.

Which defaults to the location: ${basedir}/src/main/webapp

However, the only manifest that is generated is within the war. It doesn't make sense to me either that the generated manifest file would be put into my source. I would think that it would be put in the target where the war is packaged from.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Bueller? The only option I see is to generate two separate manifest files (the second manifest for the attached artifact, generated through an ant-run execution).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the [built-in lifecycle reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) you will see that at no point in the `<packaging>war</packaging>` lifecycle is the `war:manifest` goal bound to any phase.

Thus by default this goal will not execute (unless you add an execution).

If there is a `MANIFEST.MF` file at `${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` then when the `war:war` goal is executing it will use that file rather than generating the `MANIFEST.MF` on the fly and embedding it straight into the `.war` file without creating an intermediary file.

From what I can tell, the `war:manifest` goal is designed to be used to generate a template `MANIFEST.MF` which you can then customise and use going forward.

The war plugin has a number of goals which I would tend to advise keeping clear of:

- `war:inplace`
- `war:manifest`

The reason is because both of these goals modify the files in your `src` tree which goes against the standard Maven practice of only touching files in `target` (which makes for a very nice `mvn clean` as you need only remove the target)

With regards to your question, the key thing is that you are generating a separate artifact. Maven works best when you stick to one artifact per Maven module. Thus the separate artifact will have a separate module. You just add the `.war` as a dependency (remember `<type>war</type>`) and then use `dependency:unpack-dependencies` to unpack the `.war` file... you can have it only unpack the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and if that ends up as `target/${project.build.finalName/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` then when you are packing up this second artifact you will ensure it has the same manifest as your `.war` file.

Comment: The war plugin however allows for configuration of a manifest file using the maven archiver (http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html). This is how I have done it, without an execution.

If that's true about the purpose of the war:manifest file, then yeah, I don't want to use it, since part of my manifest file is a timestamp, updated with every build.

As for the multiple artifacts, I supposed it's more of a cultural issue with these two artifacts sticking together everywhere. I see the value in separating them out (once I got over the urge to jump to defend why we do it).

Comment: I suppose I was hoping for a straightforward solution, but what you've said makes more sense of the documentation I quoted. I would like to see the manifest file "staged" in target like all the other files bound to be in the war though.

Comment: In maven-war:plugin:3.2.3 (2019-05-23) the war:manifest goal doesn't exist anymore.  Once again, maven falls short and makes comparatively simple use-cases very hard.

Comment: Interesting that using the war:exploded goal, the MANIFEST.MF file does not get generated.   Ref. [MWAR-86](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-86?focusedCommentId=14457636&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14457636)